# is it possible to perform classification on an image as small as 4x4 image using deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am new to deep learning. I was trying to understand the basics of image classification and followed some tutorials on MNIST data set classification. I saw various standard models used 224,224 as the image size. I got stuck at a point when it comes to image size which can be used for classification. Is it possible to use images as small as 4x4 to perform classification task in deep learning using ANN or other techniques? or is there any lower image dimensions limit which must be followed strictly? please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no limit for image dimensions but if you lower the dimension, the information gets lost. For example, what would you represent with a 4x4 image?

Comment: @quasimodo thanks for your reply. say in case if an image is split into smaller tiles and if we need to classify those tiles into different classes, there the size of the tiles will be very small. is it possible to classify those smaller tiles into different classes?

Comment: I believe that you should try some small models and see/observe the results...